# Need to set values in columns of dataset based on value of 1 column

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have a `Dataset<Row>` in java. I need to read value of 1 column which is a JSON string, parse it, and set the value of a few other columns based on the parsed JSON value.

My dataset looks like this:

```
|json                     | name|  age |
======================================== 
| "{'a':'john', 'b': 23}" | null| null |
----------------------------------------
| "{'a':'joe', 'b': 25}"  | null| null |
----------------------------------------
| "{'a':'zack'}"          | null| null |
----------------------------------------
```

And I need to make it like this:

```
|json                     | name  |  age |
======================================== 
| "{'a':'john', 'b': 23}" | 'john'| 23 |
----------------------------------------
| "{'a':'joe', 'b': 25}"  | 'joe' | 25 |
----------------------------------------
| "{'a':'zack'}"          | 'zack'|null|
----------------------------------------
```

I am unable to figure out a way to do it. Please help with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function `get_json_object` exists in Spark. 
Suggesting, you have a data frame named `df`, you may choose this way to solve your problem:

```scala
df.selectExpr("get_json_object(json, '$.a') as name", "get_json_object(json, '$.b') as age" )
```

But first and foremost, be sure that your `json` attribute has double quotes instead of single ones.

**Note:** [there is a full list of Spark SQL functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/). I am using it heavily. Consider to add it to bookmarks and reference time to time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use UDFs

```
def parseName(json: String): String = ??? // parse json
val parseNameUDF = udf[String, String](parseName)

def parseAge(json: String): Int = ??? // parse json
val parseAgeUDF = udf[Int, String](parseAge)

dataFrame
.withColumn("name", parseNameUDF(dataFrame("json")))
.withColumn("age", parseAgeUDF(dataFrame("json")))
```